# How many independent Probability Distributions are there?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are a [zoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) of probability distributions, some of them are special cases of or can be obtained from each other: for example [Chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) is the sum of the squares of independent [Gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

So is there are set of "essential" distributions from which other distributions can be derived from? Something like a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra))? For instance, can we say something like "all distributions can be decomposed to a sum of Gaussians", similar to the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)?

I just find it odd that all these distributions are separate from each other and are defined specifically for each experiment/situation they are designed to model.

Comment: Have you seen this page and the imposing map on it? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions

Comment: All distributions is too much.  Any function $F(x)$ which has the following three properties can be a distribution. 1)  $F(x)$ is monotone increasing, 2) $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} F(x)=0$,and 3)$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} F(x)=1$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I believe you also need right-continuity for $F$ to be a distribution.

Comment: @user6247850 I forgot.